# best practice to iterate through array of arrays & create another array

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an Array of Arrays such as:

```
Arraylist<myObjec> subArray = {item1_1,item1_2, item1_3}
Arraylist<myObjec> subArray = {item2_1,item2_2, item2_3, item2_4}

Arraylist<myObjec> mainArray = {subArray_1,subArray_2}
```

I want to create the newArray to be something like that:

```
newArray = {item1_1, item1_2, item2_1, item2_2, item1_3, item2_3, item2_4}
```

So I want to take a segment of item say get from every subArray 2 item and go back through array of Arrays till I finish.

what would be the best practices to approach this result?

**Update:**

I tried with this recursive function:

```
try {
  postList = CreateOneListFromSubArrays(mySmoraTemp, postList, 0, countSublArray(mySmoraTemp), 2);
} catch (Exception c){

}

private ArrayList<MyItemClass> CreateOneListFromSubArrays (ArrayList<SmoraItem[]> _array, ArrayList<SmoraItem> result,int n, int _size, int _sectionSize){
  if(result.size() < _size){
    for (int i=0; i<_array.size(); i++){
      for (int j=n; j<n+_sectionSize; j++) {
        result.add(i, _array.get(i)[n+j]);
      }
    }
    n += 1;
    CreateOneListFromSubArrays(_array, result, n,  _size,  _sectionSize);
  }
  return result;
}
```

but I wonder is there a better way?

Comment: Do you tried some way to perform this ?

Comment: The code you provided will never compile. Many problems with it. As Darleison says, give us a more concrete example of what you have tried.

Comment: This is no Android specific question but belongs to the Java questions...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to make it recursive. And one for loop to twice of size of the sorter array is enough.

```
    int array1[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,8,7,5};
    int array2[] = {11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88};
    int result[] = new int[array1.length + array2.length];
    int y = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < array2.length * 2 ;) { // twice of the sorter's length

        result[x++] = array1[y];
        result[x++] = array1[y + 1];
        result[x++] = array2[y];
        result[x++] = array2[y + 1];
        y+=2;
    }
```

This is not the soution, you have to find the sorter array first and after this loop you have to handle the remaining elements in the longer array.